# Make my Billing and Shipping Fields Match

Tags: javascript

I want to make my Billing fields automatically match my Shipping fields. I can make it work  with text values, but I can't automatically populate a RADIO BUTTON. I'm using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/aDNH7/ I would like to keep this in Javascript.

```
<script>
function FillBilling(f) {
  if(f.billingtoo.checked == true) {
    f.billingname.value = f.shippingname.value;
    f.billingcity.value = f.shippingcity.value;
  }
    if(f.billingtoo.checked == false) {
    f.billingname.value = '';
    f.billingcity.value = '';
  }
}
</script>
<td bgcolor="eeeeee">
<b>Mailing Address</b>
<br><br>
<form>
Name:
<input type="text" name="shippingname">
<br>
City:
<input type="text" name="shippingcity">
```

/>
        Checking
      
      
        />
        Savings

```
<br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="FillBilling(this.form)" name="billingtoo">
<em>Check this box if Billing Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
<p>
<b>Billing Address</b>
<br><br>
Name:
<input type="text" name="billingname">
<br>
City:
<input type="text" name="billingcity">
```

/>
        Checking
      
      
        />
        Savings

​

```
BUT, I want to add this to the form for both the BILLING and SHIPPING. And then I want the SHIPPING one to match up with the BILLING one if I check the box.

<!-- <td colspan="2"><p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="acct" value="checking" id="acct_0" <?php if ($user_info['acct'] == "checking"){ echo "checked='checked'"; }?>/>
    Checking</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="acct" value="savings" id="acct_1" <?php if ($user_info['acct'] == "savings"){ echo "checked='checked'"; }?>/>
    Savings</label>
  <br />
</p>
</td>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("acct_0").setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aDNH7/7/)

Comment: First, thanks for the quick reply. I checked your JSFiddle... I see the Checking and Savings Radio Buttons on the bottom, but I don't see them on the top. I am going to try to work with the code you just sent, but can you further explain?

Comment: @user1899209 I just added your inputs to the html in the jsfiddle, I'm not sure what you mean by on the top. I thought your main issue was that you wanted to mark a specific radio button as `checked`? All I did above was select one of the radio buttons and set the `checked` attribute to `checked`.

Comment: Ah ha. Please let me clarify. I have the Shipping address on top. The Check box will Auto fill the Billing address. I want to Add the Checking or Savings radio group to both billing and shipping. I want the TOP Checking and Savings radio button to cause the BOTTOM radio button to match.